# Che cos'è lo "sguancio" di una porta?

Tags: word-meaning

Nel libro *Racconto d'autunno*, di Tommaso Landolfi, ho letto:

> Davanti a una porta dipinta d'azzurro e bianco, il vecchio sostò un momento e, voltosi, scrutò dattorno; feci appena a tempo a
>   riparare nello **sguancio** della porta or ora varcata.

La mia domanda è sul significato della parola "sguancio" in questa frase. Nel vocabolario Treccani ho visto che ["sguancio"](http://www.treccani.it/vocabolario/sguancio) è lo stesso che ["sguincio"](http://www.treccani.it/vocabolario/sguincio), termine definito in questo modo:

> In architettura, conformazione di un vano, o di una struttura muraria, caratterizzata da due superfici piane verticali formanti angolo ottuso: *strutture a s.*; *s. di una finestra*, il vano a pareti divergenti verso l’interno (detto anche *strombatura* o *strombo*).

Il problema è che non capisco bene questa definizione. Per questa ragione vi chiedo: qualcuno di voi mi saprebbe spiegare cos'è lo "sguancio" o "sguincio" di una porta?

Comment: Ho trovato su wikipedia l'illustrazione di un portone che presenta uno sguincio https://it.wikipedia.org/wiki/Strombatura. Significa che lo stipite è fatto a forma di trapezio; serviva a far entrare meglio la luce.
Qui http://www.tbcad.it/guide_software/8603/it/source/modelloTerreno/aperincassi3.jpg una sezione di una finestra con uno sguincio

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Secondo il [*Grande dizionario della lingua italiana*](http://www.gdli.it/JPG/GDLI18/01036.jpg), "sguancio" significa:

> **Sguàncio<sup>1</sup>**, sm. Parte di muro costruita obliquamente in corrispondenza di stipiti e architravi; strombatura. 
>       *A. Manetti*, 2-115: Quella diminuzione sarà cagione col tempo di grandi inconvenienti, massime aggiuntovi e
>   mancamenti di poi nel murare di fuori, per certa ignoranza di capimaestri stativi, poi che presono gli sguanci degli occhi dallo lato di fuori troppo larghi. *C. Boito*, 266:
>   Lo zen abbassò la testa, come un can barbone scottato; poi se ne andò nello sguancio di una finestra. *Pirandello*,
>   7-490: Rimanevano., di qua e di là, gli sguanci nella grossezza del muro, come tante nicchie. *C. Carrà*, 371: Nello sguancio dello stesso arcone sono dipinti S. Ambrogio, S. Gerolamo, S. Agostino e S. Gregorio.

Nel contesto del testo della domanda, significa che il muro aveva una parte obliqua in corrispondenza con lo stipite della porta: questa parte obliqua è lo *sguancio* della porta.

Comment: Nell'edilizia, ma anche nella falegnameria, a Roma ho sempre sentito usare sguincio invece di sguancio

Comment: @WalterTross: Può darsi che questo sia dovuto al fatto che Landolfi usa un linguaggio un po' Ottocentesco.